# Nexus 7 console snag?

Tags: console, tablet, nexus-7

I've been messing around with the console on my nexus 7 tablet and the other day while trying to do some simple commands it returns "no devices" before hand it would usually give a serial number of the device. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Using : terminal IDE

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to tell us what commands you were trying to do...

Comment: @0xDAFACADE its irrelevant because the device is not found. A simple ls returns ''no device found''. That along with any ADB command